# C++, Pushing into List<Class*>, vector<Class> iterator

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector, iterator

I got vector< C_Student > and I must make a function that returns a List< C_Student* >. At this point I have this in the function

```
    list<C_Student*> listt;

    for (vector<C_Student>::iterator it = V_Students.begin(); it != V_Students.end(); it++)
        if (it->GetDegreeByDisciplineName(disciplineName) == degree)
            listt.push_back(*it);
```

which gives

`Description    Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=C_Student *, _Alloc=std::allocator<C_Student *>]" matches the argument list C++_Project`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try getting address `&*it`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By

```
listt.push_back(*it);
```

you try storing a copy of `C_Student` in list. To push pointer into list you need to use `&` operator to dereferenced `*it` object:

```
listt.push_back(&*it);
```

---

Elements in vector are invalidated when vector is modified, it can lead to dangling pointers in your list. I hope you are aware of it.

Comment: So its better to save copy of the student than a pointer to it right?

Comment: If you are sure that after creating the list, the vector will not be modified, you can stay with what you have. If the invariance of vector is not guaranteed, copies of students are safer.

Comment: If the list is only for displaying the "data", its okay right? Getting it in a function and looping though while printing each. Then the list is destroyed

Comment: yep, in this case it is safe.